# Parallel.ForEach with list<string> return repeated or empty data

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

The code should execute some POST method to the server and based on the information received fill a list of elements.
Code is something like:

```
var parallelResult= Parallel.ForEach(myList,
    new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(
            (Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 3.0))
    },
    item => {
        msg = string.Empty;
        msg = item.fullName;
        var balance = users.balance(item.id);
        if (balance.amount > 0 && balance.isReady)
        {
            var sendResponse = users.send(item.id, balance.amount);
            tbeResponse data;
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tbeResponse>(sendResponse);

            if (data.success)
            {
                _context.users.Add(item);
                msg += " added : " + sendResponse;
                q++;
            }
            else
            {
                msg += "could not be added: " + sendResponse;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            msg += " balance=0";
        }
    });

if(parallelResult.IsCompleted)
    _context.SaveChanges();
response.Add($"{q} were added to the database. And need to be signed");
return Ok(response);
```

Problem is the response object.
I can contain repeated elements, repeated fragments, inconsistent messages or missing elements like:

```
Diego Maradona
Diego Maradona
Diego Maradona could not be added:
Diego Maradona added : {json response}
Ariel Ortega balance 0
Lio Messi  balance=0  balance=0  balance=0
10 were added to the database. And need to be signed
```

There should be a problem with the `msg+` piece of code, but not finding a way to fix this.
The `int q++` element works fine. Problem is with string and when adding information to the variable in `msg+="some text"`

Any idea?

Comment: _"Problem is with string and when adding information to the variable in msg+="some text"

Any idea?"_ - yeah, don't append to a single string variable from multiple threads? Let each parallel code block write to its own variable, and append that to a thread-safe collection.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster how to do that? How to use it on a parallel function?

Comment: I would highly recommend reading a bit about thread safety before trying to do anything multi threaded. Multi threaded code is  much more difficult to write, and it is very easy to cause bugs, and not all bugs will be as obvious as this one. So my recommendation would be to stick with single threaded code until you know about race-conditions, deadlocks, and  other hazards of multi threading.

Comment: You need to do some systematic study in multithreading, before attempting to write parallel code. Here is a good online learning material: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari.